# PHPSpec and WordPress

Tags: testing

I installed PHPSpec and I'm wondering how should I get the WordPress environment up and running in order to run my tests;

Essentially, now I can't access anything from the WordPress API as the test file is outside the environment. Does anybody have any idea what should I load in order to make it work?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You should include `/wp-load.php`, that will load all of WordPress' functions, etc.

Comment: Works if I load it in the HelloWorldSpec.php file but I'm still not able to make load it the bootstrap.

Comment: I'm not sure how you mean...I've never worked with PHPSpec, but it seems like it's a working solution if you can get it to work...you've probably made a typo somewhere I'd guess.